# Disable direct value editing in input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have using`<input type="number">`. in that i don't want user can enter manually numbers in to input. user only increase and decrees numbers by step then is it possible.

Comment: Try this: [Spinner - jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to disable one particular function of an element like that, but it certainly would be possible to replicate by creating two buttons of your own and making the input read only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by cancelling the `keydown` event. Either inline (`<input type="number" onkeydown="return false">`), or within an event handler.

Comment: What happens if I paste a number over it? Or use a virtual keyboard that doesn't register keydown events(but does register keypress).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
$('input[type="number"]').keydown(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `readonly` attribute to input.

```
<input type="number" readonly>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6Dv2/16/)**

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/KGC3Y#0 - They want the arrows on the input, read only mode get's rid of them. It's not an answer to the users question.

Comment: @scragar, but PO did not mention whether he wants to use inbuild arrows or have extra buttons to increase / decrease.

Comment: in that case you would also be expected to post code to provide the method of incrementing or decrementing the value. You did not, hence I downvoted it because it doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: In that case let PO decide, is that what he is looking for.

Comment: i think the OP clearly stated that  "***i don't want user can enter manually numbers in to input. user only increase and decrees numbers by step***" **BY STEP**